# How do I debug wireless problems on a mobile app when it has to be wired to run in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, windows-mobile, wireless

I'm trying to track down some bugs on a Windows Mobile 5.0 app.  The testers can reproduce these bugs no problem, but I can't.  They are using the devices across a wireless network, but I'm always running the app in an emulator, or on the actual device while it's in its cradle.  In other words I always have a hard-wired connection.

I'm not sure how to approach this.  Boatloads of logging?  Is there some way to get Visual Studio to "Start Debugging" across the wireless connection?  How does one effectively debug wireless connection issues on a mobile device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the debugger working over the wireless by [manually running conmanclietn2.exe and cmaccept.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708.aspx), but the fact that the debugger is then using the connection may well affect your testing (depends on what the issues you're trying to find are).  Your best bet is to use logging.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try is to enable the WLAN connection when you're device is in the cradle (I assume it now switches off the WLAN connection when you cradle it, which is the WM5 default).

If you're using Vista, go to the Windows Mobile Device Center and under Mobile Device Settings go to Connection Settings. Make sure the Allow Data Connections On Device When Connected To A PC option is ticked (I think the option is called the same in ActiveSync in case you're using XP). That way you will have an active WLAN connection when trying to debug through the cradle.

Comment: This is tenuous at best.  Many times networking code will just grab the first available adapeter, and since ActiveSync actually shows as an RNDIS adapter, your code will often just grab it.  Trust me, I've done a *lot* of wireless code (including wrapping all of WZC).  Logging is far easier and reliable.

Comment: You could of course unplug the network connection of your dev machine, so you know any network/internet connection will go over the WLAN.
Not saying that logging isn't a good idea, but if one doesn't have time to implement it, this might be a workaround.